# Google Play Services are not being added

Tags: android, eclipse, google-play-services, eclipse-adt

This question was asked a lots of time.

But I am facing a different problem that I have imported Play Services in the workspace; I have one project which is having Play Services and it is working fine.

When I am creating another project, It is not importing and showing the error.

[image]

Comment: i also faceing this problem but now sloved

Comment: have u change worksapce and added playservie from android sdk not in workspace

Comment: I am telling you that I have one project in the same workspace having playservices in that; it is working fine.The project and playservices are in the same workspace. @Naveen Tamrakar please tell me the reason if you have fixed this issue.

Comment: where is playservie its on worksapce and android sdk

Comment: in workspace and android sdk's ..\adt-bundle-windows-x86-20140702\adt-bundle-windows-x86-20140702\sdk\extras\google\google_play_services\libproject\google-play-services_lib

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to import the project and library with selection of option(copy in work space). If you are not checked option of copy in work space it will not be attach with your project.